# A good way to use dictionary to format translated strings in Django templates?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I'm using Django 1.3, so I can't use key-value arguments for custom tags. I know about filter formatstring, but it can't use key-value arguments, anyway.
So the goal is to use this:

```
_("s %(x)s") % {'x': 'hey'}
```

But in templates.

Currently I'm using handwritten custom tag:

```
{% format_dict _("...") 'one' obj.one 'two' obj.two %}
```

I wonder, is there any built-in ability to use this w/o writing any custom tags? Maybe some built-in tag can do it?

Answer (score 1):

The filter stringformat can use keys and values. You can do:

```
d = { 'key': 'value' }
```

And in your template:

```
{{ d¦stringformat:"Example: (key)s" }}
```

Comment: Yea, but what if I need to set dictionary from template? I got over 20 strings to translate and just few of its can use similar dictionaries to format with.

Comment: You'll then need to modify the strings or the dictionaries in your views, rather than in your templates. The alternative is to use your own template tag. As far as I know, `stringformat` is the closest answer to your question without writing a custom template tag.

Comment: Simeon, you can post it like answer, so I'll approve it.